# Azure DevOps Audit logs Group.CreateGroups for groups prefixed by [TEAM FOUNDATION] by users without permission

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams

Am investigating Azure DevOps audit logs regarding users (who are **not** Project Collection Admins) appearing to create Groups.

The groups all have the following in common:

- a GroupName that starts with "[TEAM FOUNDATION]\\"
- they appear to be AD Groups related to Microsoft Teams' Teams

Can you confirm if activity like the below is done by the Azure Active Directory integration and not by the non-admin user indicated?

- Id: redacted
- CorrelationId: redacted
- ActivityId: redacted
- ActorCUID: redacted
- ActorUserId: redacted
- ActorUPN: user#1@mycompanydomain.com
- AuthenticationMechanism: S2S_ServicePrincipal
- Timestamp: redacted
- ScopeType: Enterprise
- ScopeDisplayName: mycompany (Organization)
- ScopeId: 696d346f-db...9a-18e120110d16
- ProjectId: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
- ProjectName: blank
- IpAddress: redacted
- UserAgent: VSServices/16.173.30403.3 (w3wp.exe) (Service=tfsprodweu3)
- ActionId: Group.CreateGroups
- Data: {"ScopeId":"2468cd06-7d...e9-470b591bcade","ErrorOnDuplicate":"True","Groups":[{"Sid":"S-1-9-155...28022-2234316434","Id":"e0e9d112-64...c7210a69","ScopeId":"2468c...e9-470b591bcade","Name":"*Group Name without [TEAM FOUNDATION] prefix*","Description":"*a description*","VirtualPlugin":null,"SpecialType":5,"ScopeLocal":false,"RestrictedView":false,"Active":true}],"EventAuthor":"e972bfe1-0...43b8961","AddActiveScopeMembership":"False","CallerProcedure":"prc_CreateGroups","GroupId":"e0e9d1...2ac7210a69","GroupName":"[TEAM FOUNDATION]\*Group Name*"}
- Details: [TEAM FOUNDATION]\*Group Name* group was created
- Area: Group
- Category: Create
- CategoryDisplayName: Create
- ActorDisplayName: name of user #1 at my company

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help.

Answer (score 0):

> GroupName that starts with "[TEAM FOUNDATION]\"

This means that the group is an AAD group.

> Can you confirm if activity like the below is done by the Azure Active Directory integration and not by the non-admin user indicated?

This should not be AAD integration automatically adding AAD group to organization.

Based on my test, when you see this record in Auditing log, this means that the AAD Group has been added to the Organization manually by name of user #1 at my company .

Comment: to clarify - so when a group is added to Azure AD you **don't** think this is automatically synchronised to Azure DevOps? This is a manual action by the above user? This user shouldn't have had permission to do this so are you sure this could not be initiated from Azure AD automatically?

Comment: I tried to create a new AAD group , but it will not show in the auditing log. Only when I manually added the AAD group, it will show the record in Auditing log.